# Jupyter Notebook not getting launched

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am using Windows 10. My Jupyter Notebook version is 6.0.1. I am trying to launch the notebook using command `jupyter notebook` in anaconda prompt. Nothing happens and it gets stuck. In the `tasklist`, it shows the jupyter notebook running.

Comment: There will a link provided in the terminal. Try opening that in a browser.

Comment: It is not displaying any link. Just blank screen. I tried opening the port 8888 on my default browser.